# Translation of a Latin verse in a book on the history of mathematics

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

A latin poem by Friedrich Leo appears in a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0915692287) I have read for some time, and the author cited a part of it(the complete version can be seen [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ONhNAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA210&lpg=PA210&dq=%E2%80%9CVnde%20mathematicis%20lumen%20praeluxit%20Hamilto%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=fEKB4cnArb&sig=ACfU3U2xfkjguRfRO6glT7W07sNHHYvzBA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVhaiL7-rqAhXMvJ4KHdgVBPoQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)) when he was talking about [Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Rowan_Hamilton)

> Unde mathematicis lumen praeluxit Hamilto

**Question:** What is the most adequate translation for the cited part(as the book I am reading does not contain the English translation of the poem)? Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Nam quis commemoret tot nomina quisve requi..* (unreadable)
> *Nomina quae mundus mente animoque tenet,
>
> Quisve roget, quos Musa recens, quas Gratia nuper
> Eductos illa duxerit alma domo,
>
> Vnde mathematicis lumen praeluxit Hamilto,
>
> Hippocratis pueris Stokius unde facem,
>
> Cuius et e rivis hortos, quicumque vetustas
>
> Graia ac Romana est cura laborque, rigat.*

The verses were part of a long Ode written in praise of 'famous names' all from one place of learning, probably Trinity College Dublin.

> "For who may remember so many...
> Names which the world holds fondly
> in mind and heart..."

Then ...

> "Who is asking which [Deities] led forth the educated from the College (the Alma Domo)...

Then, your quotation,

> From which Hamilton, a luminary in Mathematics, shone out   /blazed forth,
> *Vnde mathematicis lumen praeluxit Hamilto,*

From which, *unde,* means 'from this college.'
*lumen,* light, is nominative, cognate with *Hamilto.*
I would rewrite it as
"College...from which Hamilton, a luminary in Mathematics, shone out."

Comment: These verses are elegiac couplets. There should be a line break before "Eductos" in your third line.

Comment: The first line ends *requirat* (see OP's second link).

Comment: A couple of small corrections: the *mathematicis* are presumably people, i.e. "a light to mathematicians"; in the preceding line the meter shows that *illa domo* go together, while *alma* has to be nom. with *Gratia* (though I'm not sure why *quas* is fem. -- a typo?); and *roget* is subj., "who would ask...".